# Jquery script targets all my divs in a count script, Want it to work individually for each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a jquery script that counts words and adjusting the font-size based on the amount of words. The problem is that it counts all the attributes with h1 in the parent. I want it to count individually for each h1. The originally script is marked as h1:first. Here is the script where it counts all h1 in the class wofa:

```
$(function(){

var $quote = $(".wofa h1");

var $numWords = $quote.text().split(" ").length;

if (($numWords >= 1) && ($numWords < 3)) {
    $quote.css("font-size", "1px");
}
else if (($numWords >= 3) && ($numWords < 6)) {
    $quote.css("font-size", "5px");
}
else if (($numWords >= 20) && ($numWords < 30)) {
    $quote.css("font-size", "10x");
}
else if (($numWords >= 30) && ($numWords < 40)) {
    $quote.css("font-size", "15px");
}
else {
    $quote.css("font-size", "1px");
}
```

});

Comment: im going to check but im sure you can do a "for each" function which will loop through all the .wofa , because the way it is set up now it will just check one and then css all the h1's with that class.

Comment: I didn't entirely understand your question, but you probably want to use `$quote.each`. jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the .each() method with your selector and nothing was selected.

I ended using $('.wofa, h1).each():

```
$('.wofa, h1').each(function() { 
    var words = $(this).html().split(" ");
    alert($(this).html() + ' has ' + words.length + ' words');
});
```

Here's a working version on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/russianator/jKPdQ/

Comment: I tried that code and it counted all the words of my h1. The problem is when i tried to enter my code to adjust font-size.

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var words;
            var quote = $('.wofa h1').each(function(){
                numWords = $(this).html().split(" ");
                alert($(this).html() + ' has ' + words.length + ' words');
    
    if (($numWords >= 1) && ($numWords < 3)) {
        $quote.css("font-size", "1px");
    }

This code did not change the font-size only call which one out.

Comment: I'll try adding a font-size change to my jsfiddle and reply back :)

Comment: Thanks that would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I think your selector "inside" the each isn't working, try mine again. http://jsfiddle.net/russianator/jKPdQ/5/

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**  Working Example [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/tacgh/)

You can use the .each() function

```
$('.wofa').each(function() {
    var quote = $(this).find('h1');
    var numWords = quote.text().split(" ").length;
    console.log(numWords);
    if ((numWords >= 1) && (numWords < 3)) {
        quote.css("font-size", "1px");
    } else if ((numWords >= 3) && (numWords < 6)) {
        quote.css("font-size", "5px");
    } else if ((numWords >= 20) && (numWords < 30)) {
        quote.css("font-size", "10x");
    } else if ((numWords >= 30) && (numWords < 40)) {
        quote.css("font-size", "15px");
    } else {
        quote.css("font-size", "1px");
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work. Every h1 still has the same font-size as original h1.

Comment: @JacobJohansson Hmmm...thats strange, Can you show your html?

Comment: <a href="#" class="wofa"><h1><span>Learn HTML!</span></h1></a>

One of the elements.

Comment: Notice that i tried changing your code from h1 to span. Still didn't work.